# OpenMP C Program Clarification

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

If you want to access the thread-local values of a privatized variable from outside of the parallel scope, you can write them back to a globally declared auxiliary array. This is the way it was described in an OpenMP book

> (2017 - Bertil Schmidt, Jorge Gonzalez-Dominguez, Christian Hundt,
>   Moritz Schlarb - Parallel Programming_ Concepts and Practice-Morgan
>   Kaufmann)

Authors came up with this program --

```
int main () { 

    // maximum number of threads and auxiliary memory  

    int num = omp_get_max_threads(); 

    int * aux = new int[num]; 

    int i = 1; // we pass this via copy by value 

    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(i) num_threads(num) { 

        // get the thread identifier j 

        int j = omp_get_thread_num(); 

        i += j; 

        aux[j] = i; 

    } 

    for(k=0; k<num; k++) 

        printf("%d \n", aux[k]); 

}
```

Tried this in Mac -->

[image: Error message]

What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `gcc-9` by `g++-9`?

Comment: This is not a C program, clearly it is C++, please fix your tag(s).

Answer (score 0):

`new` is not an operator of `C` . `new` is for `C++` , in `C` you can allocate memory with other function like `malloc`.

as you can see in the error , it says `new undeclared` because this operator is not defined in `C`.(it's like using an unknown name)

So it expect you to add some thing here `new int[num];` because it's like this

```
unknown_name/*add something like ;*/ int[num];
```

instead of `new` , you can use something like this:

```
int *aux=malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
```